# width formatters in C

Tags: c

I came across a strange question.

Given this program :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%04d",100);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 0100, I can understand why. If I change it to

```
printf("%04.1d",100);
```

The output I am getting is  100 with a blank in front of 1. 0 is ignored. My question is how does width formatter work in these cases?

Comment: Like [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p4)

Comment: Read the man page.

Comment: dude, i know how it works. I am just asking does it make sense to use decimal while printing integers? why the zero is omitted?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Reminded of BLUEPIXY. :-)

Comment: @J...S I take it as a compliment. Should I?

Comment: When I compiler and run the source you show, I get “0100”, with no blank character in front. Are you sure you get a blank in front and that is the exact source you used?

Comment: for the second one, yes

Comment: @EugeneSh. Linking to the ISO standard is hardly appropriate.

Comment: @nicomp Linking to the *specific paragraph* answering the question is hardly appropriate? Really?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes. Really.

Comment: @nicomp OK, flag it then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `%d` if a precision (which specifies the minimum number of characters) is specified then the `0` flag is ignored, since it is performing a similar function.

The man page states the following regarding the `0` flag:

> The  value  should  be  zero padded.  For d, i, o, u, x, X, a, A, e,
>   E, f, F, g, and G conversions, the converted value is padded on the
>                 left with zeros rather than blanks.  If the 0 and - flags both appear, the 0 flag is ignored.  **If a precision is given 
>   with  a  numeric
>                 conversion (d, i, o, u, x, and X), the 0 flag is ignored.**  For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.

And the following regarding precision:

> An  optional precision, in the form of a period ('.')  followed by an
>   optional decimal digit string.  Instead of a decimal digit string one
>   may
>          write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that the precision is given in the next argument, or in the m-th  argument,
>   respectively, which must be of type int.  If the precision is given as just '.', the precision is taken to be zero.  A negative precision
>   is taken as
>          if the precision were omitted.  **This gives the minimum number of digits to appear for d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions**, the number
>   of digits to
>          appear after the radix character for a, A, e, E, f, and F conversions, the maximum number of significant digits for g and G
>   conversions, or the
>          maximum number of characters to be printed from a string for s and S conversions.

In your case, since you specified 1 for the precision, then 1 character minimum needs to be printed.  Had you used 4 for the precision, you would have gotten a single leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

The standard formatters are [well documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). The `%d` one in particular is for integer, "decimal" values. This means the `.` separator is meaningless here since those don't have any particular precision like floating point values require.

That notation is reserved for situations like:

```
printf("%04.1f", 3.9);
```

Which would give you `03.9`, four characters for the field, one decimal place, one point of precision.

In the case of `%d` the precision value is interpreted differently:

> Precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear. The default precision is 1.

It has an entirely different meaning, but it's rare to see that particular aspect of it used.

Comment: I think you meant to put 03.9 instead of 0.39

Comment: @C_Elegans I thought I put that in there, thanks for pointing that out.